# What is wrong with this function call

Tags: c++, qt

Behold the code:

```
QImage *qi = new QImage(fullCharArray, imwidth, imheight, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
ui->viewLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qi,Qt::AutoColor));
```

Why does this give me an error? What is it trying to get me to change the qi argument to in the call to fromImage? I am relatively new to C++ and it seems like I am setting this up correctly. It works if I change the line to

```
QImage *qi = new QImage(fullCharArray, imwidth, imheight, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    ui->viewLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qi[0],Qt::AutoColor));
```

But is that the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because [QPixmap::fromImage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qpixmap.html#fromImage) expects a reference to an image, not a pointer to one.

However, change your qi[0] to *qi, that makes the intention cleaner. (or just refrain from using a pointer and start with `QImage qi(fullCharArray ...`).

Answer (score 2):

Generally it might help, if you give the error message in your question. Now from looking at qts online documentation I think your problem is the following:

you are trying to pass qi which is of type `QImage*` to [QPixMap::fromImage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qpixmap.html#fromImage), which exepects a `const QImage&`, so a reference to QImage. Therefore what you have to do is dereference `qi`:

```
ui->viewLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*qi,Qt::AutoColor));
```

This is basically identical to your second version `ui->viewLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qi[0],Qt::AutoColor));`, since `ptr[i]` is defined as `*(ptr+i)`, so `ptr[0]` means basically `*(ptr+0)` which is `*ptr`. However using `*` for dereferencing here makes it clearer that you dereference a pointer to a single object, instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `QPixmap::fromImage` takes a `QImage` as first argument, not a `pointer to a QImage`.

Answer (score 0):

qi is a pointer, and setPixmap looks like waiting for an object, so that's why the first version fails.

Correct way is

```
QImage *qi = new QImage(fullCharArray, imwidth, imheight, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
ui->viewLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*qi,Qt::AutoColor));
```